# Subgroup of $S_n$ that has no subgroups of index 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

> Let $n\geq5$, and $G$ a subgroup of $S_n$ s.t. $G$ has no subgroups of index 2 ($G$ is also simple). Is this enough to say that $G$ lays in $A_n$ (as $A_n$ is simple and has no subgroup of index 2)?

Is there any use of the 2nd isomorphism theorem to prove this? i'm working on a group of order 2016 and for n=8 ($o(G) \leq o(A_{8})$)

Comment: You don't need to assume that $G$ is simple, because if $G$ is not contained in $A_n$, then $G \cap A_n$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$.

Comment: Well by the use of the 2nd isomorphim theorem, i can see that $G \cap A_{n}$ is normal in $G$.. but i don't understand why it is a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$

Comment: Because $|S_n:A_n|=2$.

Comment: Aaah i see, we use the fact the $\left| G : G \cap A_{n} \right| \leq \left| S_{n} : A_{n} \right| = 2 $, and as $G$ is not contained in $A_n$ , $G \cap A_{n} \neq G$ and the index can't be equal to $1$, thank you very much Derek, it seems more clear now =)

Answer (score 2):

We do not need *whether $A_n$  is simple or not*; we need to know that its index in $S_n$ is $2$, which is true for all $n\geq 1$. You may ignore also the hypothesis that $G$ is simple.

Suppose $G$ is not in $A_n$ (but it is in $S_n$ by htpothesis). Then $GA_n=S_n$ and hence $G\cap A_n$ is subgroup of index $2$ in $G$ (use the formula for $|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|$ or any other way).

This contradicts another hypothesis. Hence $G$ must be in $A_n$.

Comment: Slight correction:  $A_n$ has index 2 in $S_n$ only when $n > 1$ (not $n \geq 1$).

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is simple non commutative, $[G,G]=G\subset [S_n,S_n]=A_n$ done.

Comment: Interesting fact, but what if we do not know that $G$ it is simple, but just that it does not have a subgroup of index $2$ ? does this still true ?